# Choice Exception Strategy doesn't work in Mule

Tags: exception, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Below is a exception strategy part of the flow

```
<choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
            <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(java.sql.BatchUpdateException)" doc:name="SQL deadlock error">
                <logger message="SQL EXCEPTION - RETRYING BATCH PROCESS"
                    level="ERROR"  doc:name="Payload Logger" category="asi_user"/>
                <set-variable variableName="Exception" value="User" doc:name="Exception Type"/>
                <flow-ref name="Reload_Batch" doc:name="Retry Batch Results"/>
            </catch-exception-strategy>
            <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException)" doc:name="SQL error">
                <logger message="SQL EXCEPTION - RETRYING BATCH PROCESS"
                    level="ERROR" category="asi_user" doc:name="Payload Logger" />
                <set-variable variableName="Exception" value="User" doc:name="Exception Type"/>
                <flow-ref name="Reload_Batch" doc:name="Retry Batch Results"/>
            </catch-exception-strategy>
            <catch-exception-strategy  doc:name="Unexpected errors">
                <logger message="UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION - SEND EMAIL NOTIFICATION"
                    level="ERROR" category="asi_user" doc:name="Payload Logger" />
                <set-payload value="#[exception.cause.message]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
                <flow-ref name="Send_Error_Notification" doc:name="Send Email Notification"/>
            </catch-exception-strategy>
        </choice-exception-strategy>
```

Even when a java.sql.BatchUpdateException is thrown from the flow, the control goes to the final exception strategy "Unexpected Errors", it doesn't go to SQL deadlock error

Am I missing anything to make it work.

Could any please help me with this to make it work.I'm using is Mule server 3.4.0 EE

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try printing the exception.getClass() in your "unexpected Error" section and check whether the exception is "java.sql.BatchUpdateException".

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the problem with your expression in the when

Try it the following way.

```
<catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(java.sql.BatchUpdateException)]" doc:name="SQL deadlock error">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please upvote answers. This helps in improving the search results when this issue is searched again.